# object.getfolder error variable of bloc with not defined

Tags: excel, vba

Im writting a code to import all files of a folder into one excel sheet. here is my code:

```
Sub ImportLiabs()
Dim destination As String
Dim Colonne1Tableau As Integer
Dim Ligne1Tableau As Integer
Dim nb_onglets_param As Integer
Dim OngletMacro As String
Dim i As Integer: i = 1
Dim folder As String

  'Paramétrage
destination = ThisWorkbook.Name
Dim NomFichier() As String

Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object, file As Variant
folder = Range("Folder").Value
Set MyObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set MySource = MyObj.GetFolder(folder)
For Each file In MySource.Files

        If Left(file.Name, 9) = "liab_data" Then

        i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve NomFichier(i)
        NomFichier(i) = file.Name

        Workbooks.Open file
        Sheets.Copy After:=Workbooks(destination).Sheets(i)
        Windows(NomFichier(i)).Close


        i = i + 1


    End If
    Next file


End Sub
```

the problem is that when excecuting it displays , variable or object not defined of block with at this line:

```
Set MySource = MyObj.GetFolder(folder)
```

Cant manage to figure what the problem is, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You're defining the variable `MyObject` but then using `MyObj` to set the folder.

Try this:

```
Set MyObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set MySource = MyObject.GetFolder(folder)
```